# Using parent instance in child class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, design-patterns

I'm not sure what this pattern is called, but I wanted to understand if that is considered a good/bad practice.

So, I've `Base.class` that creates a `Children.class` instance. Now, in Children class I've an async callbacks A, B, C. I've to react on these async callbacks - but all methods that I need to call on these callbacks are in `Base.class` as it works as main controller and messages other submodule about new changes.

Very often the simple solution here is to create `Callbacks`  A1, B1, C1 in between `Base` and `Children` class. What I hate about this scenerio is that I basically have to duplicate all Children async callbacks (A, B, C) to `Base` and `Children` callbacks (A1, B1, C1). Can't I just pass `Base` class instance in `Children` and use open functions that way avoiding duplicating similar callbacks that basically does not do anything other than transporting data to different place later on?

Is it bad practise or what?

Comment: perhaps you're looking for [delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html) pattern

Comment: This is just like an Android Fragment containing a reference to its Activity and Context. Not that you should necessarily always look to Android for good practices. I think they regret making Activity extend Context. But the androidx/support libraries were less rushed.

Comment: Have `Base` implement an interface, have the child accept the interface type instead of `Base`and have the child interact with the parent via the interface. You can then later decide on a better implementor to avoid having `Child` access to the base instance (via casting).

Comment: An instance of the child class is an instance of the parent class, why do you have to pass instances around? Also, actual code and not only prose would help you to understand and communicate.

Comment: @Smutje He didn't say he was using inheritance: "*I've Base.class that creates a Children.class instance*" - sounds like he's using composition.

Comment: @VinceEmigh it is actually right in the title of the question. What should a "parent" and a "child" class be anything else than inheritance in Java context?

Comment: @Smutje The parent would be the one who composes the child: the parent holds the instance of the child (via a field), and when the parent is dereferenced, so are the members (children) it's composed of. Think in terms of a tree, where leaf nodes would be the children of root nodes.

Comment: This question feels like it should be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Usually this is a bad practice. Occasionally it's fine.  It depends on why the Children class exists in the first place and what the purpose of the children instances are.

Comment: Could you create a small example which shows a problem? It would be easier to help and talk about solution.